# Is GNU linker "ld" creating undefined reference to `fftw_alloc_complex

Tags: fft, fftw

Thje error that I got ae as follows

```
fftw_oct.f90:(.text+0x26a): undefined reference to `fftw_alloc_real'
/usr/local/bin/ld: fftw_oct.f90:(.text+0x3a7): undefined reference to `fftw_alloc_complex'
/usr/local/bin/ld: fftw_oct.f90:(.text+0x4fb): undefined reference to `fftw_alloc_complex'
```

Is this error arises due to GNU LINKER ?

Answer (score 0):

The linker doesn't invent references; if you have an undefined reference, it means you (or something you linked) made a reference to something you didn't link.

That can mean a couple of things - for example, you could be missing a library on your link line (check for missing `-l` flags), or that something you compiled contained conditionals that weren't enabled (`#ifdef` and the like), so those symbols were omitted.

If it didn't give you heck at *compile* time (check your warnings), you likely have a header that contains declarations of the missing symbols. That should help you narrow down the location of their implementations.